# Attempting to Benchmark (time) my JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, time

I am attempting to benchmark a bubbleSort algorithm. I used to time my functions in Python with `time.time()` and wanted to attempt the same thing with JavaScript:

```
var time;
function bubbleSort(array) {

    /*Function Time Starts Here*/
    var start = Date.now();

    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
            if (array[j - 1] > array[j]) {
               _a = [array[j], array[j - 1]], array[j - 1] = _a[0], array[j] = _a[1];
            }
        }
    }

    /*Function Time Ends Here*/
    var end = Date.now(); 

    /*Total Time*/
    time = end - start;

    return array;
}

console.log("Time bubbleSort finished: " + time + "ms. Result:", bubbleSort([9, 8, 4, 3, 2, 5, 6, 7, 1, 10]));
```

My expectation is the variable `time`, which is undefined in the global scope, will be initialized to the value in the inner scope of `bubbleSort`. When I run this in PythonTutor, `time` does initialize to a number in milliseconds, but what gets printed in the console is `Time bubbleSort finished: undefinedms. Result: [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ]`. Why does `time` log undefined when it does initialize to a number value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the way the contents of `console.log` are executed. `time` is undefined when it is logged because you have not yet called `bubbleSort`. You need to call `bubbleSort` and THEN log the time.

```js
var time;
function bubbleSort(array) {

    /*Function Time Starts Here*/
    var start = Date.now();

    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
            if (array[j - 1] > array[j]) {
               _a = [array[j], array[j - 1]], array[j - 1] = _a[0], array[j] = _a[1];
            }
        }
    }

    /*Function Time Ends Here*/
    var end = Date.now(); 

    /*Total Time*/
    time = end - start;

    return array;
}
var result = bubbleSort([9, 8, 4, 3, 2, 5, 6, 7, 1, 10]);
console.log("Time bubbleSort finished: " + time + "ms. Result:", result);
```

Also, I think you will need to use `window.performance.now()` because millisecond resolutions are too large for performance timing.

```js
var time;
function bubbleSort(array) {

    /*Function Time Starts Here*/
    var start = window.performance.now();

    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
            if (array[j - 1] > array[j]) {
               _a = [array[j], array[j - 1]], array[j - 1] = _a[0], array[j] = _a[1];
            }
        }
    }

    /*Function Time Ends Here*/
    var end = window.performance.now(); 

    /*Total Time*/
    time = end - start;

    return array;
}
var result = bubbleSort([9, 8, 4, 3, 2, 5, 6, 7, 1, 10]);
console.log("Time bubbleSort finished: " + time + "ms. Result:", result);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Why does time log undefined when it does initialize to a number value?

Sequence in which logging happened was

1. Static string
2. **time** variable //not initialized yet
3. Static string
4. **bubble sort function execution** //time initialized now but logging already done.

Since you have logged `time` before it is initialized/defined, you see `undefined`.

Change it to

```
console.log(bubbleSort([9, 8, 4, 3, 2, 5, 6, 7, 1, 10]), "Time bubbleSort finished: " + time + "ms. Result:" );
```

**Demo**

```js
var time;
function bubbleSort(array) {

    /*Function Time Starts Here*/
    var start = Date.now();

    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
            if (array[j - 1] > array[j]) {
               _a = [array[j], array[j - 1]], array[j - 1] = _a[0], array[j] = _a[1];
            }
        }
    }

    /*Function Time Ends Here*/
    var end = Date.now(); 

    /*Total Time*/
    time = end - start;
    return array;
}

console.log(bubbleSort([9, 8, 4, 3, 2, 5, 6, 7, 1, 10]), "Time bubbleSort finished: " + time + "ms. Result:" );
```